# How to get serde_with::nested::json dependency imported properly

Tags: rust, serde

I'm trying to use the setup as outlined in the serde_with docs here to deserialize nested json into my struct: https://docs.rs/serde_with/1.4.0/serde_with/json/nested/index.html

After a few tries Cargo.toml file looks like:

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
//serde_with = { version = "1.4.0", features = ["..."] } // this doesn't work even though that's what the serde_with README calls for
serde_with = { version = "1.4.0", optional = true }
serde_json = "1.0"
```

Trying the above I get an error such as:

```
#[serde(default, rename(deserialize = "Plan"), with="serde_with::json::nested")]
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type or module `serde_with`
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example the module `serde_with` is not optional and must provide the feature `json`.

Replace

`serde_with = { version = "1.4.0", optional = true}`

with

`serde_with = { version = "1.4.0", features = ["json"]}`

**Full example:**

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0" }
serde_json = "1.0"
serde_derive = "1.0"
serde_with = { version = "1.4.0", features = ["json"]}
```

main.rs

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde;
extern crate serde_json;

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct A {
    #[serde(with = "serde_with::json::nested")]
    other_struct: B,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize)]
struct B {
    value: usize,
}

fn main() {
    let v: A = serde_json::from_str(r#"{"other_struct":"{\"value\":5}"}"#).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(5, v.other_struct.value);
    let x = A {
        other_struct: B { value: 10 },
    };
    assert_eq!(r#"{"other_struct":"{\"value\":10}"}"#, serde_json::to_string(&x).unwrap());
}
```